# Clean your files with sourcetree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a file that has been changed from encoding by someone.
However if I check the file on my system it has still the old encoding.
Some files however got the new encoding.

It seems that sourcetree/Git thinks the file hasn't been changed because it is only the encoding that has been changed.

So is there a way in sourcetree to a sort of cleanup and pull or refresh of this file even if he thinks it is the same version?

I don't work with commandline, so please give me the commands in sourcetree.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use sourcetree, so I can't tell you whether it has a menu item somewhere to resolve this issue. The commandline command is pretty obscure, so I'd be surprised if it has.

The command you need to run after someone changed the work tree file encoding or line-ending settings in the git attributes file is:

```
git add --renormalize .
```

A simpler solution may be to simply create a fresh clone of the repo.